# Displaying the sub content of a particular list of item thats clicked.

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of values being displayed using Map on a list of item, it has a sub-content that's hidden by default, and is supposed to SHOW when I click on that particular item, right now when I click on a list all the hidden sub-contents are being displayed.

// show and hide are CSS classes that have properties display: none and display: block

```
class App extends Component {
      state={
        show: false
      }

      show = (e) => {
        this.setState({
          show: true
        })
      }
      render() {
      const list = [1,2,3,4,5];
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <ul> {list.map((item, index) => 

              <div key={index}> 
                <li onClick={this.show}> {item} </li>

                  <p className={this.state.show? "show": "hide"}> Hello </p>

              </div>)}</ul>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Right now all of your sub-content classes are tied to a single piece of state, which is why they will all show on click. You'll have to restructure your application a little differently to make this work. Consider making your list items into their own component with their own visibility state.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to maintain the state of each subitem vs the global "show" property you got going on now.

Notice how currently no matter which subitem you click you change the one boolean you have in state, which is the "show" property. Since this is set to true, this applies to *all* of your subitems.

There's a few ways to go about this but one possible solution that doesn't involve making a separate `Item Component` is to maintain each subitem's status in state with a dictionary:

```
state = {
    items: {
        0: {show: false},
        1: {show: false},
    }
}
......./////////////
show = (index) => (e) => {
    const {items} = this.state;
    let updatedItems = [
        ...items.slice(0, index),
        {show: !items[index].show},
        ...items.slice(index + 1)
    ];

    this.setState({
        items: updatedItems
    });
}
......./////////////
<li onClick={this.show(index)}>
```

This might seem verbose, but if you don't want to mutate state it's currently best practice.

In all honesty it might be easier to just create a separate Item component, that way they can maintain their own state easier.

More reading on lists and keys and immutability:

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/handling-state-in-react-four-immutable-approaches-to-consider-d1f5c00249d5

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html